# Store object as datetime before while loop

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, while-loop

I'd like to use a while loop get the time difference between the current row and the previous row in a pandas data frame. To provide some context, here is my sample code:

```
counter = len(data)-1
last = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
current = last
while((last-current).seconds() <= 60 and counter>-1):
                # Do something
       data[counter]
```

However, I received this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'
```

From what I understand, `datetime` functions does not work with pandas series, so there's at least two ways to go about with solving this:

1) Store `last` as a datetime object to take advantage of the `.seconds()` `datetime` function

2) Use the pandas version of the `(last-current).seconds()` `datetime` function

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Attached Data Structure Sample**

```
{'time': {0: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:23:12'), 1: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:23:32'), 2: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:23:52'), 3: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:24:12'), 4: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:22:12'), 5: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:24:32'), 6: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:24:52'), 7: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:25:32'), 8: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:30:12'), 9: Timestamp('2016-03-28 23:29:12')}, 'Origin': {0: 'Boston', 1: 'New York', 2: 'Boston', 3: 'New York', 4: 'Hawaii', 5: 'Hawaii', 6: 'Miami', 7: 'Las Vegas', 8: 'Hawaii', 9: 'New York'}, 'Destination': {0: 'Miami', 1: 'Miami', 2: 'Miami', 3: 'Boston', 4: 'Boston', 5: 'New York', 6: 'Las Vegas', 7: 'Las Vegas', 8: 'Las Vegas', 9: 'Los Angeles'}}
```

---

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Can we see a sample?

Comment: If you already have a DataFrame or Series, could you please post the output of `data.head(10).to_dict()`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need:

```
data['time'].diff()
```

Here's the output:

```
0                 NaT
1            00:00:20
2            00:00:20
3            00:00:20
4   -1 days +23:58:00
5            00:02:20
6            00:00:20
7            00:00:40
8            00:04:40
9   -1 days +23:59:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

**Edit in response to comment**

There are several ways you can approach getting the total seconds.

```
In [12]: data['time'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
Out[12]: 
0    NaN
1     20
2     20
3     20
4   -120
5    140
6     20
7     40
8    280
9    -60
Name: time, dtype: float64

In [13]: timeit data['time'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
1000 loops, best of 3: 738 µs per loop

In [14]: data['time'].diff().map(lambda td: td.item(), na_action='ignore')*1e-9
Out[14]: 
0    NaN
1     20
2     20
3     20
4   -120
5    140
6     20
7     40
8    280
9    -60
Name: time, dtype: object


In [15]: timeit data['time'].diff().map(lambda td: td.item(), na_action='ignore')*1e-9
1000 loops, best of 3: 381 µs per loop
```

Or better yet, :

```
In [17]: np.divide(data['time'].diff() , np.timedelta64(1, 's'))
Out[17]: 
0    NaN
1     20
2     20
3     20
4   -120
5    140
6     20
7     40
8    280
9    -60
Name: time, dtype: float64

timeit np.divide(data['time'].diff() , np.timedelta64(1, 's'))
The slowest run took 4.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer works. For one thing, we can't verify if the time difference between the current and previous row is 60 seconds because of invalid syntax.

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation check out the edit. I'm not sure how you want to deal with negative time-differences, but it should be easy from this point to do whatever you want.